# Style element if contains a certain word, CSS3 only

Tags: html, css

I want to style an element based on the text that is written inside of it.

```
<div class="target-element">
  Cat
</div>
```

And if I was guessing how the CSS should look:

```css
.target-element[content="Cat"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This doesnt work of course ^^ , which is where the help comes in.

Comment: You can't do it with pure CSS, you need to use JQuery with `:contains()`

Comment: i guess you can use :empty pseduo in CSS but not any content . I am going to agree with @SimonM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this only with [css](/questions/tagged/css).

If you can use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) I would take a look at this example: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/469131/jIn-hear-we-have-a-single-class-But-I-want-colour

```
var content = $(".target-element").text();
if (content == "Cat") {
    content.css("background", "red");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute to the `div` and catch that to change the css as

```css
div[data-color="red"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="target-element" data-color="red">
  Cat
</div>
```

Comment: The element should change its color to red based on the word 'Cat'. Without 'Cat', the text is simply black.